# Is there a way to use Small Capitals in the Bibliography?

Tags: bibtex, small-caps, author, bibliographystyle

I'm going mad trying to have the author name in the bibliography in small caps as required by the publisher; I found two Bibtex styles  acm adn siam that should do this, but the resulting has everything in normal font, no small caps and not even italics for the title.

So, I opened the bbl file, produced by the bibtex command of Texnic center / MikTex: with my surprise the file had the \sc and \em, that should be obsolete, rightly in their environment but not working, producing normal font. I tried the simple trick of replacing '\sc ' with '\scshape ' and '\em ' with 'itshape' in the bbl file, and gave the build command again. Here is the first item:

```
{\scshape Al-Kadi, I.}
\newblock Origins of cryptology: The arab contributions.
\newblock {\itshape Cryptologia\/} (1992).
```

It worked fine for the title now in italics as required, but the scshape did not work, author name still and stubbornly in normal font, here is  a cut and paste from the pdf.

[image]

I use the Garamond font, required by the publisher; using the same font with Microsoft Word it works fine producing small caps titles where required.

Looks like someone hates small caps!!

Can somebody explain the mystery?

Paolo Boonavoglia

---

**Update**

Thanks to the hint I have solved the problem: in fact Garamond font does not have small caps, so I put a

```
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}[]
```

just before the \bibliographystyle{acm} and finally author's name was in smallcaps, so

[image]

but titles were underlined instead of the required italics; thereafter I made a find & replace  \em with \itshape in the .bbl file,  made a new build, then I made a dull change to the .bbl file and save it again, so the system believed it to be new and then another build. Now the bibliography had the desired look:

[image]

A question was still open: why using Word and Garamond, you get small caps all the way?? I don't know the answer, but I can easily guess it is not difficult to implement small case with any font: just write the uppercase as they are, and lowercase using uppercase with a reduced size ... you do not really need a font having small caps of its own. Why Latex people do not do the same? Or maybe there is already some package for this?

Another problem remains: citations are limited to a number e.g [24]; I would like something more readable. Any hint? Maybe trying another style?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please provide a bit more information about you document setup. E.g., which document class do you employ?

Comment: Not all font have small case feature.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! Could you edit your code to begin with your `\documentclass{}` and end with `\end{document}` , a [Minimal Working Example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) please. It makes copy and pasting easier when the code can be compiled and also we do not need to guess what commands or packages you are using.

Comment: Designed small caps often have a slightly different shape or different proportions than full caps, and in traditional typography have slightly wider side-bearings.  Setting regular uppercase at a smaller size is possible, but an inferior emergency substitute.

Comment: let it be clear: I'm not proposing to do it . I'm only trying to guess how Microsoft Word can have smallcaps for every font, even those like Garamond that do not have smallcaps among their glyphs. I presume Microsoft  has software engineer able to optimize that resizing..